# how to use yylval with union in yacc

Tags: c, bison, yacc

I was confused about how to use `yylval` defined in `%union{}`, when `yylval` is a `int`, I can use `$1` and `$2` reference to tokens, but with union type I don't know how to do. I got definition here:

```
%union {
    int intval;
    double floatval;
    char *strval;
    int subtok;
}
```

For example, I have a rule when yylval is string like this

```
line: SELECT items'\n' { printf("select item %s\n", $2); };
```

how to change it to `strval` instead?

Comment: Declare the type of each grammar symbol. Eg. `%type <strval> items`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare the type of each token when declaring the token...

```
%token <strval> items
```

Declare the type after declaring the token...

```
%type <strval> items
```

Or specify the type when grabbing the value...

```
$<strval>2
```